# Java 8 stream to Map<K,List<String>

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to use Java 8 Streams to read file and add lines to map by appliying spesific rules. My file is like this:

> 2 
>  54 4 13 167 5 7
>  23 96 24 3

First line shows size and other lines what I want to put into my map. I did this but the problem is count of numbers changable. How could I get all Stream[] elements other than first element

```
Map<Integer, String> kvs = stream
                .skip(1)
                .map(elem -> elem.split(" "))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> Integer.parseInt(e[0]),
                 e -> e[1]+" "+e[2]));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate what result exactly you're trying to get? It's a bit unclear (at least to me).

Comment: I want to put the  data into a Map<Integer,String> or Map<Integer,List<String>> . elem.split(" ")) parse the whole String on the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to use everything after the first space as the map value, you can use two-argument [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-):

```
Map<Integer, String> kvs = stream
            .skip(1)
            .map(elem -> elem.split(" ", 2))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> Integer.parseInt(e[0]), e -> e[1]));
```

The parameter 2 instructs split not to make more than two fields, so the rest of the string will be put into `e[1]` even if it has more spaces.

Comment: did not know such a method event exists. :) thx

Comment: I did not know the split method the way you used. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not *exactly* sure what mapping you want to achieve, a helper class will make things clearer and give you the flexibility to perform any mapping:

```
static class LineMapper {
    private int key;
    private List<String> value;

    public LineMapper(String line) {
        int i = line.indexOf(' ');
        if (i < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        key = Integer.valueOf(line.substring(0, i));
        value = Arrays.asList(line.substring(i + 1).split(" "));
    }

    public int getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public List<String> getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can perform the mapping:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> kvs = stream
        .skip(1)
        .map(LineMapper::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(LineMapper::getKey, LineMapper::getValue));

    System.out.println(kvs);
}
```

Comment: A helper class saved my day to understand more implementing stream methods, thank you